# Sendkeys() method in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

The method `sendKeys(CharSequence...)` in the type `WebElement` is not applicable for the arguments `(double)`

```
wd.findElement(By.id("----")).sendKeys(sheet.getRow(2).getCell(0).getNumericCellValue());
```

How can I get numeric cell value from Excel into sendkeys method, for string value it's working fine.

Now I am using poi jar files

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, convert the numeric value to string. like String str = ""+5;

for your case use ""+sheet.getRow(2).getCell(0).getNumericCellValue()

i.e

wd.findElement(By.id("----")).sendKeys(""+sheet.getRow(2).getCell(0).getNumericCellValue());

In case of numeric cells, apache poi returns double value. to get the exact double values, i.e with out character 'E', convert the double value to BigDecimal and get it's String representation, like below

```
Double d = 1.234567E8;
String str1 = new BigDecimal(d).toString();
System.out.println(str1);
```

Output : 123456700
That's all

Comment: it is converting Numeric value into 1.234567E8

Comment: Use BigDecimal class, refer the below sample code and execute in your ide. 

Double d = 1.234567E8;
String str1 = new BigDecimal(d).toString();
System.out.println(str1);

Comment: Tanks for u r support

Comment: How can we get Date value from Excel to Sendkeys() method in webdriver

Answer (score 0):

since "Sendkeys()" only accept String as an argument, so if u want to pass a numeric value into sendkeys, you have to convert it into String. I'll take an example to explain this in detail.

Suppose u get "1455" from excel and u want to pass it to sendkeys then convert it into String like this:

```
String num = Double.toString("1455");
webElement.SendKeys(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

SendKeys requires a String object to be passed, but you're passing it a numeric value.

Try this instead:

```
WebElement element = null;
try {
    element = wd.findElement(By.id("----"));
    element.sendKeys(sheet.getRow(2).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
    );
} catch (Exception e) {
    /* this is thrown if the cell contains a formula that isn't a "string Formula" */
}
```

Note that I've changed the `getNumericCellValue()` for `getStringCellValue()`.